# Formatting bound data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding

i have a DataGridView that is bound to a list of objects. One of the the parameters of the objects is a price which is in cents and i would like to show in dollars, if i were to write it out directly i would do the following:

```
row.Cells[5].Value = String.Format("€ {0:0.00}", oStockData.netPriceCents / 100);
```

i could go over the data afterwards but cannot commit the new formatted string to the bound object so only need the data displayed in another format.

As far as i can see it i have these options:

1. Save the actual base data in a non-browsable parameter and create
   another which can be changed to the required format and shown to the
   user.
2. Change the data when the datagridview is populated, then change it
   back to the original format when required.

Is there are better way because the 2 above just seem dirty to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any dirty in having "viewmodel" which represents data in the way user/UI need.

```
public class OrderLineViewModel
{
    private OrderLine _model;

    public OrderLineViewModel(OrderLine model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _model.Price/100.0m;
        }
        set
        {
            _model.Price = value * 100.0m;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve your data and "wrap" it with viewmodel class which will represent your data in UI way.

```
var data = GetOrderLines();
dataGridView.DataSource = data.Select(orderLine => new OrderLineViewModel(orderLine))
                              .ToList();
```

Format "€ 0.00" you can set in the datagridview's column settings.